# How can solve this issues? ArgumentError (Invalid argument(s): iOS settings must be set when targeting iOS platform.)

Tags: flutter, uilocalnotification, flutter-notification

How can solve this issues?

`ArgumentError (Invalid argument(s): iOS settings must be set when targeting iOS platform.)`

I had added the Notification, but when I running the iOS simulator I get this error `How can solve this issues? ArgumentError (Invalid argument(s): iOS settings must be set when targeting iOS platform.)`

But it's can working real devices, just cannot working iOS simulator

Comment: Have you set Push notification capability in Xcode?

Comment: Yes, I have do it, I could received FCM notification at real device. But could not running at iOS simulator

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Push notifications do not work on iPhone simulators.They require a provisioning profile from iTunes Connect, and thus are required to be installed on a device.so if it is working fine on real devices, then no need to worry.

Comment: But, I need to try to code on simulator...@@  So just change to real device to test and development?

Comment: yes, check notification part on real devices, rest all you can do on simulator.